# How to create array of object from two different length of array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to create array of object from two different length of array

for example

```
arr1 = ["first","second","third","fourth","fifth","Sixth"]
arr2 = [["1","2","3","4","5","6"],["7","8","9","10","11","12"],["1","2","3","4"]]

finalArray = [{
   first:1,
   second:2
   third:3,
   fourth:4,
   fifth:5,
   sixth:6
},{
   first:7,
   second:8
   third:9,
   fourth:10,
   fifth:11,
   sixth:12
}]
```

I tried this using map but getting every key value pair as whole object

example

```
[
 {first: 1}
 {second: 2}
 {third: 3}
 {fourth: 4}
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const arr1 = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "Sixth"];
const arr2 = [["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
              ["7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"],
              ["1", "2", "3", "4"]];

const res = arr2.map(v => v.reduce((a, v, i) => ({...a, [arr1[i]]: v}), {}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I feel this is a bad approach because it has poor runtime complexity: you're using the spread-operator (which will perform an `O(n)` array copy on every input element) in `reduce`.

Comment: @Dai You are correct, but for small data volumes the difference will be negligible, and if we were aiming for optimal runtime performance, we would not be using any of the array functions like `map()` or `reduce()` anyway. Another thing worth mentioning is that we don't know what optimizations the JavaScript engine introduces, so it's hard to determine actual runtime complexity. With no stipulations about performance requirements in the question, I err on the side of conciseness and readability.

Comment: So what could be the best approach beside any predefined function @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: Iterate using only `for` loops, regular property assignments to objects, push to add to array.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to update the shape of the result array

```js
let arr1 = ["first","second","third","fourth","fifth","Sixth"];
let arr2 = [["1","2","3","4","5","6"],["7","8","9","10","11","12"],["1","2","3","4"]];

let result = arr2.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  let obj = arr1.reduce((acc, currentKey, index) => {
    if(current.indexOf(index) && current[index] !== undefined ){
      acc[[currentKey]] = current[index];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return accumulator.concat(obj);
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

without `reduce()` and covered edge case when the `arr1` contains fewer elements as the element from `arr2`

```js
const arr1 = ["first","second","third","fourth","fifth","Sixth"]
const arr2 = [["1","2","3","4","5","6"],["7","8","9","10","11","12"],["1","2","3","4"]]

const res = arr2.map(values => {
    const res = {}
    for(const [index, value] of arr1.entries()){
        if(values[index]) {
            res[value] = values[index] // or parseInt(values[index])
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    return res
})

console.dir(res)
```

Comment: `if(values[index]) {` - there's a bug here: if the `values[index]` value is falsy (e.g. `0`) then your `for` loop will break too early.